# Getting error while trying to buy NFT on mainnet? Solana Metaplex/Storefront

Tags: solana, storefront, metaplex

I am getting an error while trying to buy NFT on mainnet? Created through the Solana Metaplex/Storefront.
I have enought SOL on my wallet(using Phantom)

Error: `Transaction may fail to confirm`

[image]